# flex contextmenu items in tamil

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I am developing a desktop RIA. I have a context menu which shows the suggested words. Now I getting boxes

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ba90d08e6f.png

Please have a look to the above url. 
I am using sqlite as embedded database. I am getting the suggested words in an array, that array items are added in context menu items.
I have to display text in context menu for almost all different languages.
Please suggest me how can I get the actual text instead of the boxes?

Reply ASAP

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Boxes mean (most likely) bad font.

But the menu is a system menu, is not rendered by Flash/Flex/AIR.
So it looks like your system is not configured to render Tamil (font fallback)

Since Tamil is supported since Windows 2000, it is (probably) not installed properly.
Check here: http://www.southasia.upenn.edu/tamil/unicodehelp.html
(just a guess, I don't have enough info)

In the long run, you might also discover that you have some problems with the rendering of Tamil in Flash/Flex/AIR. This is because the old Flash text engine does not handle complex scripts.

There is a new engine in Flash 10.0, but to use it you will have to download and use a helper library (http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/), or use Flex 4 (which uses the new text engine by default in the new Spark controls)